# XmlHttpRequest upload progress event firng only once and too early

Tags: javascript, file-upload, upload, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to upload a chunk of a file (using HTML5 File API, slice and XmlHttpRequest2), and to report on progress to the user.

Problem I have is that the progress event generally fires almost immediately (even with a chunk size of 5MB), with the 'loaded' value equal to the size of the chunk. Of course it can take maybe 30seconds for the chunk to upload, during which the user has no feedback.

Code below if anyone can help please? I've been almost literally tearing my hair out over this one but cannot find anyone who has come across the same issue!...

```
var startPosition = (partNumber - 1) * PART_SIZE;
var blob;

if (typeof fileUpload.File.slice != "undefined")
{
    blob = fileUpload.File.slice(startPosition, startPosition + contentLength);
}
else
{
    if (typeof fileUpload.File.webkitSlice != "undefined")
        blob = fileUpload.File.webkitSlice(startPosition, startPosition + contentLength);

    if (typeof fileUpload.File.mozSlice != "undefined")
        blob = fileUpload.File.mozSlice(startPosition, startPosition + contentLength);
}

fileUpload.PartNumber = partNumber;



        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();            

        // Add event listener for progress
        xhr.upload.onprogress = function (event) 
        {
            log.debug("progress " + event.loaded);

            if (event.lengthComputable)
                UpdateProgress(fileUpload, event.loaded);
        };            

        xhr.open("PUT", url, true);

        xhr.setRequestHeader('authorization', result);

        // Make the request an HTTP PUT
        log.debug('Sending PUT request to ' + url);
        xhr.send(blob);
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am seeing this in Google Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Answer - there's nothing wrong with the code. Something is wrong with my pc, it works fine in the same browser on a different computer.